# Organize the sequence of tuple in a Haskell List comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

Hello dear Community,

I'm trying organize the sequence of tuple in a Haskell List comprehension.

e.g. I got the following List Comprehension:

```
[ (a,b,c,d) | a <- [0, 50, 100, 150, 200]
            , b <- ['a', 'b', 'c']
            , c <- [True, False]
            , d <- ['A', 'B']
            ]
```

and get:

```
[ (0, 'a', True, 'A'), (0, 'a', True, 'B'), (0, 'a', False, 'A')
, (0, 'a', False, 'B'), (0, 'b', True, 'A'), (0, 'b', True, 'B')
, (0, 'b', False, 'A'), (0, 'b', False, 'B'), (0, 'c', True, 'A')
,(0, 'c', True, 'B'), (0, 'c', False, 'A')..
```

Now I want the sequence like following:

```
[ (0, 'a', True, 'A'), (0, 'a', True, 'B'), (0, 'b', True, 'A')
, (0, 'b', True, 'B'), (0, 'c' ,True, 'A'), (0, 'c', True, 'B')
, (0, 'a', False, 'A'), (0, 'a', False, 'B')..
```

That means: 
First a trade off between the capital letters `'A'` & `'B'`, then a trade off between the small letters `'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'`, as a penultimate the trade off between the boolean values `True`, `False` and finaly the numbers.

Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea how to realize these and i want to know how you can manipulate the sequence of a list with tuple `[(a,b,c)]`.

Answer (score 6):

The *order* of the `x <- list` statements in list comprehension is important. If you write:

```
[expr | x <- list1, y <- list2]
```

this is equivalent to a nested for loop with `y` being the inner loop. So a Python equivalent with loops would be:

```
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        expr
```

and thus the inner loop is entirely exhausted before the outer loop picks the next value.

So we need to reorder the statements such that we first pick `d`, then `b`, then `c` and finally `a`. So that means that we turn:

```
[(a,b,c,d)| a <- [0,50..200], b <- "abc", c <- [True,False], d <-"AB"]
```

(I made the lists shorter in notation)

into:

```
-- [(a,b,c,d)| a <- [0,50..200], b <- "abc", c <- [True,False], d <-"AB"]
--             |                  \_________/_____              |
--             |                   ________/      \             |
--             |                  /                \            |
   [(a,b,c,d)| a <- [0,50..200], c <- [True,False], b <- "abc", d <- "AB"]
```

(the comment is only to visualize the difference)

which generates:

```
Prelude> [(a,b,c,d)| a <- [0,50..200], c <- [True,False], b <- "abc", d <- "AB"]
[(0,'a',True,'A'),
 (0,'a',True,'B'),
 (0,'b',True,'A'),
 (0,'b',True,'B'),
 (0,'c',True,'A'),
 (0,'c',True,'B'),
 (0,'a',False,'A'),
 (0,'a',False,'B'),
 (0,'b',False,'A'),
 (0,'b',False,'B'),
 (0,'c',False,'A'),
 (0,'c',False,'B'),
 (50,'a',True,'A'),
 (50,'a',True,'B'),
 (50,'b',True,'A'),
 (50,'b',True,'B'),
 (50,'c',True,'A'),
 (50,'c',True,'B'),
 (50,'a',False,'A'),
 (50,'a',False,'B'),
 (50,'b',False,'A'),
 (50,'b',False,'B'),
 (50,'c',False,'A'),
 (50,'c',False,'B'),
 (100,'a',True,'A'),
 (100,'a',True,'B'),
 (100,'b',True,'A'),
 (100,'b',True,'B'),
 (100,'c',True,'A'),
 (100,'c',True,'B'),
 (100,'a',False,'A'),
 (100,'a',False,'B'),
 (100,'b',False,'A'),
 (100,'b',False,'B'),
 (100,'c',False,'A'),
 (100,'c',False,'B'),
 (150,'a',True,'A'),
 (150,'a',True,'B'),
 (150,'b',True,'A'),
 (150,'b',True,'B'),
 (150,'c',True,'A'),
 (150,'c',True,'B'),
 (150,'a',False,'A'),
 (150,'a',False,'B'),
 (150,'b',False,'A'),
 (150,'b',False,'B'),
 (150,'c',False,'A'),
 (150,'c',False,'B'),
 (200,'a',True,'A'),
 (200,'a',True,'B'),
 (200,'b',True,'A'),
 (200,'b',True,'B'),
 (200,'c',True,'A'),
 (200,'c',True,'B'),
 (200,'a',False,'A'),
 (200,'a',False,'B'),
 (200,'b',False,'A'),
 (200,'b',False,'B'),
 (200,'c',False,'A'),
 (200,'c',False,'B')]
```

(new lines added to make it easier to verify)